# Description of SharePoint list column in SharePoint designer xslt

Tags: xslt

have a list in SharePoint portal. Also I have added description to each of the fields in list. Now I have created a dataview webpart in SharePoint 2007 Designer. I am able to get the list column values but I em not able to get the Column description ? Can anyone tell me how can I get the description of the list column using xslt in sharepoint designer?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="@NameOfDescriptionFieldHere" />`

Comment: Here Description  is not another column. It is the description of the column which i have added. Suppose "MyColumn" is the column in the list.while creating the column I have added description to it for ex: MyColumn is the first Column"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharmila,

You cannot get the Description of the column, in DataViewWebpart, since the description which you provided becomes part of Field Description Attritbute, and the value of the Field becomes part of SPList Item.